# What's wrong with this IMG tag?

Tags: html, image

I think I am going crazy. I have an IMG tag like this:

```
<img src="/images/icon-articl.png" alt="xyz" />
```

All good, image is displayed fine.
However I want to name the image icon-article.png instead but for some reason this is not accepted!

```
<img src="/images/icon-article.png" alt="xyz" />
```

will only show the ALT text! All I did was make a copy of the image file and rename it accordingly. Doing the same with "icon-articles.png" is fine again!
When I enter the full address into the browser's address bar, the same happens, "icon-article.png" results in URL not found while the other images are shown.

What is this??

PS I don't think it matters but I am working on a localhost right now

EDIT: corrected my typo just to make sure that the code itself and filenames are fine. Problem is solved, see below.

Comment: Does this happen on your web broswers? what broswers are you using?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl F5 or Shift F5 for eliminating cache probs?

Comment: Do you have a file called `icon-article.png` in your `/images/` folder?

Comment: Okay so I just double-checked in Chrome (was using Firefox initially) and there it works - seems to be some very weird Firefox bug .... any idea?

Comment: Oh you guys were quick. alt tag is properly closed, was only part of th ecode

Comment: Okay thanks EricG, STRG-F5 did the job. hould have known that myself.

Answer (score 3):

Okay thanks everybody for your efforts, and sorry, I should have expressed myself better. The code itself was fine, what I gave in my question was only a snippet. Also all the files do exist, I always copied and renamed them.

So thanks EricG for your comment, the cache was the issue and CTRL-F5 solved the problem!

I will rember to do this more often ....

Comment: In FireFox you can disable cache for developers ;)

Answer (score 2):

close your alt tag

```
<img src="/images/icon-article.png" alt="... "/>
```

Comment: It will fix invalid HTML :)

Also, you said you renamed your file to "icon-articles.png" but your image source is "/images/icon-article.png"

If the file name includes the 's' , then include that in your source reference

Comment: Sorry, did you mean to have half your comment address the OP rather than me?

Answer (score 2):

May be  icon-article.png images is not a orginal png file if you may be rename file extension it will not supported in IE like browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/images/icon-articles.png" alt="..." />
```

I have appended 's' in image file name. as you named it, mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you change the name in the tag that you change the file-name as well. Otherwise it won't work.